# Jquery selector using $(this) handle next element by next()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I m trying to calculate profit percentage and write the value to next input .Using jquery , jstl

```
<div id="quantityHoleForPercentage">
<form:input path="quantity11Profit"  id="quantity11Profit" cssClass="smaller" />                               
</div>
<div id="quantityHoleForPercentage">
<form:input path="quantity11Price"  id="quantity11Price" cssClass="smaller" />
</div>
```

I m listening change event on  quantity12Profit and after I got this value I m multiply it with a constant and write the result to quantity11Price

But in jquery I cannot handle  $("#quantityHoleForPercentage input") in my scenerio when I changed quantity11Profit  input i  should be able to handle quantity11Price  with $(this).next();
But I can not .I m doing that beacouse of I have too much input like these.
Here is my jquery code please give some advice where I m wrong or  alternative ways
Thanks so much

```
    $("#quantityHoleForPercentage input").change(function(){                    
    var needless=$(this).attr('id');
    var willWriteToPriceInput= $(this).val();
    var priceInput=$(this).next();
    priceInput.val(willWriteToPriceInput);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#quantityHoleForPercentage input[id$=Profit]").change(function(){
  var willWriteToPriceInput= $(this).val();
  var priceInput = $(this).parent().next()
  priceInput.val(willWriteToPriceInput);
});
```

But try to change quantityHoleForPercentage from ID to Class in your html and jquery

Comment: hello @Maius llie
               $("quantityHoleForPercentage input").change(function(){                    
                    var needless=$(this).attr('id');
                    var willWriteToPriceInput= $(this).val();
                    var priceInput=$(this).parent().next();
                    priceInput.val(willWriteToPriceInput);
                   
                });

I wwrote this code and change multiple id s to classes  but i can not still handle the next element .
I guess I will write it one by one thanks

Comment: for the class selector you should change # with . in jquery

Answer (score 1):

The id `quantityHoleForPercentage` comes two times in your html, change it so that id of the control become unique.

Comment: Hello          
        $("quantityHoleForPercentage input").change(function(){                    
        var needless=$(this).attr('id');
        var willWriteToPriceInput= $(this).val();
        var priceInput=$(this).parent().next();
        priceInput.val(willWriteToPriceInput);
        });